# Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline manifest file won't pick up javascripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have a whole MESS of javascripts in vendor/assets/javascripts. In my app/assets/javascripts/application.js file, I have the directive:

```
//= require_tree .
```

Does that only reference the current app/assets/javascripts directory, and not lib/assets or vendor/assets?

If I explicitly include the javascripts, it works. I just don't really want to do that if I don't have to.

Is there something I am missing that will allow the assets pipeline to be able to serve up assets from outside the app directory (lib and vendor) automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

require_tree only pulls in assets that are under the application.js file.

`lib/assets` and `vendor/assets` are already included in the lookup paths for the pipeline ([refer this code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb#L542)).

You can include these vendored files by using a second manifest.

Go to `vendor/assets/javascripts` and create a file called misc_vendor.js

Inside that add put a require_tree directive.

Then refer to that file from your application.js manifest:

```
require misc_vendor
```

If you have any issues because of loading order you can manually require the vendor files in the order you need instead of using require_tree.

As part of the conversion to the pipeline it may be a good chance to clean up things! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can do it without a second manifest like this:

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.
```

The path should be relative to the 'app/assets/javascripts/application.js' manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend path in application.rb file like this.

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/some file name"
```

[Refer this Guide for more details](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)